# Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot', how to solve ignore: deprecated_member_use in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

In my flutter project, I have made some updates of plugins and then used flutter upgrade. After that, whenever I am running my flutter project it is showing following error-

```
    /C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-3.0.2/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:46:19: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
          io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

So, I need a suggestion that how can I solve this issue?

Comment: can you use the latest version? https://pub.dev/packages/platform/versions/3.1.0

Comment: flutter pub upgrade solve my issue

Comment: Restarting the Android Studio worked for me after upgrade & clean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me, cleaning and getting the packages didn't work. This error started after I upgraded flutter. I was on the master channel, a quick fix for me was to switch to stable.

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

Perhaps theres a better solution which deals with platform package directly.

Comment: I closed VSCode then clean and pub get. Then it worked like a charm.

Comment: Add this under dependencies => dependencies: platform: ^3.1.0. This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 193):

You need to upgrade your dependencies to fix this issue, so run:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

---

If this still doesn't work then it means you are having this issue from transitive dependencies on `platform` (`platform` with version lower than `3.1.0` has this problem). So, override the `platform` package in your `pubspec.yaml` file like this:

```
dependency_overrides:
  platform: ^3.1.0
```

Comment: I just saw `path_provider` [transitive dependency](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/path_provider/path_provider_platform_interface/pubspec.yaml) is also using `platform: 3.0.0`, and unfortunately, the latest update of `path_provider: 2.0.8` doesn't solve this issue, so you'll need to override the dependency as I mentioned in the second part.

Comment: Actually @CopsOnRoad it turns out that `path_provider` has a dependency of `platform: ^3.0.0` and not `platform: 3.0.0` so doing a `flutter pub upgrade` is all that is necessary and the override is not required for this case.

Comment: @Maks I meant it was resolved to `platform: 3.0.0` which have this issue. But I was not sure if `flutter pub upgrade` can actually upgrade the transitive dependencies. I'll update my answer then, thank you

Comment: thank you, I am also using `path_provider: 2.0.8`. I did `flutter pub upgrade` then done `flutter run` then it shows a different error. prompt of flutter fix is shown to change the `ext.kotlin_version` to latest(https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions) which in my case was `1.6.10`.
then I again run `flutter run` and the issue is fixed. So for me, there is no need for `platform: ^3.1.0`

Comment: Confirmed. `flutter pub upgrade` helped. Especially while switching branches, where the old was had not up-to-date dependencies.

Comment: thank you, its work for me after add to ```pubspec.yaml```

Comment: `path_provider: 2.0.9` seems to have a fix for this. you can skip the overriding line.

Comment: Build errors exist in your project. after run these command

Comment: flutter pub upgrade is the best solution in my case.

Answer (score 53):

Try add in pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies: // under dependencies:
  platform: ^3.1.0
```

then run  `flutter pub get`

**Why this error occurred**

`../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-3.0.0/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:46:19: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'. io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use`

this is the kind of error that you will get when you build the file.

if you notice the error was caused by package
`platform:3.0.0`

so we are just overriding this by incrementing it to `3.1.0`

Comment: Can you get a little bit more in detail, why this is working?

Comment: As @om-ha stated below, `platform` pub is out of date. Most likely in your case it's a transitive dependency from `path_provider` pub

Answer (score 34):

The only thing that could help me was to delete the `pubspec.lock` file from the project folder and only then run

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get
```

Comment: Same here. I could never get this working until I deleted `pubspeck.lock`.

Good insight, thank you.

Answer (score 21):

```
flutter pub upgrade

flutter clean

flutter pub get
```

Comment: my flutter version 2.10.1 and itsn't work for me

Comment: same not working for me also

Answer (score 10):

### Solution

#### A. deleting pubspec.lock

- Delete `pubspec.lock` file
- For good measures, update `platform`'s parent pub e.g. `path_provider` to the latest version.
- `flutter pub get`

#### B. pubspec dependency override

- Add `platform` with its latest version as a dependency override

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  # fix `packageRoot`compile error for iOS, because `path_provider` is using an old version of `platform`
  platform: ^3.1.0 # overrides `path_provider`
```

- `flutter pub get`

### Root Cause

- `platform` pub is out of date. Most likely in your case it's a transitive dependency from `path_provider` pub.
- For some reason, `flutter pub get` won't update `platform` which is a transitive dependency. Even if you change the version of its parent pub `path_provider` to the latest version and call `flutter pub get` again.

### Inspecting `platform` pub version

A. `flutter pub deps` to print package dependency graph. Then find "**- platform**" string within the output.

B. Inside `pubspec.lock` file, look for "**platform:**" string.

Comment: `flutter pub get won't update platform which is a transitive dependency.` thank you for this! I was trying to figure out why it was needed!

Answer (score 8):

firstly, run

`flutter pub outdated`

then

`flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and I have solved it with the following steps:

1. run `flutter pub upgrade`
2. run `flutter pub outdated`
3. run `flutter pub clean`

**Note**: run `flutter pub clean` in project root and in example packege.

Another important thing make sure you are on the stable version of Flutter.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it with one command:

```
$ flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it :
compileSdkVersion 31,
and upgrade kotlin-version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

For Flutter iOS Users:

After running following commands:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
flutter pub upgrade
```

After completing the process, try

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

or

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Its worked for me. Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If all solutions above doesn't work for you just like me,

If the problem occurs immedately you upgrade your flutter

1. run `fluter downgrade 2.0.1 //2.0.1 means your working previous version of flutter`
2. after downgrading, click on the extensions button or use shorcut **Ctrl+SHift+X**, then uninstall and re-install Flutter and Dart.

this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. flutter pub get
2. flutter pub upgrade

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Update your **pubspec.yaml**

```
dependency_overrides:
  platform: ^3.1.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following into the terminal at the path of your project.

1. flutter pub cache repair
2. flutter pub upgrade

Comment: I would not reccomend updating all the packages like that, most likely things will break

Comment: You don't need to update anything in your pubspec.yaml file. this will make sure your updater flutter version also updates SDK in your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.2 <3.0.0"
```

add this to pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to delete my platform dependency from pubspec.lock.  I tried deleting the entire file, but that caused other problems.  Deleting the offending entry in this file and then doing these commands worked for me:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory, delete the two files:

- .flutter-plugins
- .flutter-plugins-dependencies