# BUILD FAILED in 3m 27s Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... 210.0s Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart

../Downloads/flutter_windows_2.10.0-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-3.0.0/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:46:19: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'
.
io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\foldername\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.10.0-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\foldername\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.10.0-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Have tried flutter clear and all but error still exist

Comment: Try updating your dependencies in pubspec.yaml to the latest versions as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70757512/14228678)

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean your project folder by running command `flutter clean`

2.Update flutter package
you can simply run `flutter pub upgrade` in your project to upgrade all the packages.
3. Then run `flutter pub get`

Now build you project

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with platform, a dependency needs upgrade try:

`flutter pub upgrade`