# Cannot compile - member not found: package root

Tags: flutter, dart

My error code:

```
../../Documents/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/flutter/.pubcache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-3.0.0/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:46:19: 
Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
  io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              ^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I went to update pub, as this seemed related to some plugin, and I'm getting this error:

```
Expected to find project root in current working directory.
```

Since I'm a supernoob I am a total loss. What would you do in my shoes?

Comment: This will solve it [Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot', how to solve ignore: deprecated_member_use in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70363918/error-member-not-found-packageroot-how-to-solve-ignore-deprecated-member-u)